# Pandas groupby resample poor performance

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

### My problem

I'm having trouble with the performance of resample function in combination with a groupby. The operation I'm doing is currently taking 8+ seconds on a data sample of 5000 rows which is totally unreasonable for my requirements.

### Sample data (500 rows)

Pastebin with data as dict: https://pastebin.com/RPNdhXsy

---

### The logic

I have data with dates in a quarterly interval which I want to group by a column and then resample the dates within the groups on a monthly basis.

```
Input:
     isin  report_date   val
    SE001   2018-12-31     1
    SE001   2018-09-30     2
    SE001   2018-06-31     3
    US001   2018-10-31     4
    US001   2018-07-31     5

Output:
    isin   report_date      val        
    SE001   2018-12-31        1
            2018-11-30      NaN
            2018-10-31      NaN
            2018-09-30        2
            2018-08-31      NaN
            2018-07-31      NaN
            2018-06-30        3
    US001   2018-10-30        4    
            2018-09-31      NaN
            2018-08-31      NaN
            2018-07-31        5
```

I used to have this operation:

```
df.groupby('isin').resample('M', on="report_date").first()[::-1]
```

Since it seems that `asfreq()` has slightly better performance than using `on=` in `resample`, I instead do the following currently. It's still slow though.
I reverse since `resample` seems to non-optionally sort dates descending.

```
df.set_index('report_date').groupby('isin').resample('M').asfreq()[::-1]
```

As stated, with 5000 rows and around 16 columns this takes 15 seconds to run since I need to do it on two separate dataframes. 
With the sample data in the pastebin (500 rows) the operation takes me 0.7s which is way too long for me since my final data will have 800k rows.

### EDIT: Timing of the different operations

**Current way**

```
setindex --- 0.001055002212524414 seconds ---
groupby --- 0.00033092498779296875 seconds ---
resample --- 0.004662036895751953 seconds ---
asfreq --- 0.8990700244903564 seconds ---
[::-1] --- 0.0013098716735839844 seconds ---
= 0.9056s
```

**Old way**

```
groupby --- 0.0005779266357421875 seconds ---
resample --- 0.0044629573822021484 seconds ---
first --- 1.6829369068145752 seconds ---
[::-1] --- 0.001600027084350586 seconds ---
= 1.6894s
```

Judging by this, it seems that converting from the `pandas.core.resample.DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby` to a df is taking very long. Now what?

### EDIT2: Using reindex

```
df.set_index('report_date').groupby('isin').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min(), x.index.max(), freq='M'), fill_value=0))[::-1]
```

This takes 0.28s which is a vast improvement. Still not very good though.

---

How can I speed this up? Is there another way to do the same thing?

Comment: This sounds a bit slow.  How long does it take when you run the groupby and resample on separate lines?  By breaking it up can you identify whether the bottle neck is in the groupby or resample calls?

Comment: @tnknepp See my edit

Comment: I think you are right, the dataframe creation is the bottleneck.  My only suggestion is to perhaps not resample to 1M resolution.  You start with quarterly data so everything with higher resolution will just have NaNs...though you may have a reason for doing this.

Comment: @tnknepp I perform operations later on which fill the NaNs with the correct data. I need each month to be its separate row since they're going in the database after all the data transformation and calculation is done.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, willing to upsample time series *after* a groupby. I tried both of the above methods above (which yield the same performance for my use case), and could not use @Mark Wang way, because of memory usage.

Comment: Your sample dataset has expired.

Answer (score 2):

I cut execution time for a 25k row test data set from 850 ms to 320 ms.  I wrapped the reindex logic in a function, to make timing easier:

```
def orig_pipeline(df):
    return (df
            .set_index('report_date')
            .groupby('isin')
            .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min(), 
                                                     x.index.max(), 
                                                     freq='M'), 
                                       fill_value=0))
            [::-1])
```

Then, I created new functions to make date arithmetic and reindexing faster:

```
def create_params(df):
    return (df.groupby('isin')['report_date']
            .agg(['min', 'max']).sort_index().reset_index())

def create_multiindex(df, params):
    all_dates = pd.date_range(start='1999-12-31', end='2020-12-31', freq='M')
    midx = (
        (row.isin, d)
        for row in params.itertuples()
        for d in all_dates[(row.min <= all_dates) & (all_dates <= row.max)])
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(midx, names=['isin', 'report_date'])

def apply_mulitindex(df, midx):
    return df.set_index(['isin', 'report_date']).reindex(midx)

def new_pipeline(df):
    params = create_params(df)
    midx = create_multiindex(df, params)
    return apply_mulitindex(df, midx)
```

Old and new pipelines give same results (except possibly sort order):

```
v1 = orig_pipeline(df).drop(columns='isin').sort_index()
v2 = new_pipeline(df).sort_index().fillna(0)
assert(v1 == v2).all().all()
```

Timing results:

```
%%timeit
v1 = orig_pipeline(df_big)
854 ms ± 2.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
v2 = new_pipeline(df_big)
322 ms ± 5.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, that is the one that yields the best performance on my specific dataset. Bounty has been awarded. I will post my experiments below as another answer. Do you by any chance know why coding the resample logic in python shows performance improvements compared to the pandas implementation?

Comment: Regarding performance improvements: `pd.date_range()` is slow.  The utility function `create_multiindex()` calls date_range once, to create the month-end dates.  Then, it uses boolean indexing to extract dates for data set.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to illustrate the experiments I made trying to figure which solution yields the most performance, and it shows that @jsmart 's is the best one.

My dataset is like the following (sorry for the screenshot I could not manage to paste a pretty table):

[image: Dataframe to process]

My goal is to have for each (orgacom, client) couple the indicators resampled by business day.

**Solution 1: groupby / apply asfreq**

```py
%%time
sol1 = (
to_process.groupby(['orgacom', 'client'], observed=True, )
          .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('B', fill_value=np.nan))
)
```

*CPU times: user 4min 6s, sys: 2.91 s, total: 4min 9s*
*Wall time: 4min 9s*

**Solution 2: groupby / apply reindex (as of @jokab EDIT2)**

```py
%%time
sol2 = (
to_process.groupby(['orgacom', 'client'], observed=True, )
    .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min(), x.index.max(), freq='B'), fill_value=np.nan))
)
```

*CPU times: user 4min 13s, sys: 2.16 s, total: 4min 15s
Wall time: 4min 15s*

**Solution 3: recoding resample (as of @jsmart answer)**

```py
def create_params(df):
    return (df.reset_index().groupby(['orgacom', 'client'], observed=True, )['date']
            .agg(['min', 'max']).sort_index().reset_index())

def create_multiindex(df, params):
    all_dates = pd.date_range(start='2016-12-31', end='2020-12-31', freq='B')
    midx = (
        (row.orgacom, row.client, d)
        for row in params.itertuples()
        for d in all_dates[(row.min <= all_dates) & (all_dates <= row.max)])
    return pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(midx, names=['orgacom', 'client', 'date'])

def apply_mulitindex(df, midx):
    return df.set_index(['orgacom', 'client', 'date']).reindex(midx)

def new_pipeline(df):
    params = create_params(df)
    midx = create_multiindex(df, params)
    return apply_mulitindex(df, midx)

%%time
sol3 = new_pipeline(to_process.reset_index())
```

*CPU times: user 1min 46s, sys: 4.93 s, total: 1min 51s
Wall time: 1min 51s*

**Solution 4: groupby / resample asfreq (as of @jokab first solution)**

```py
%%time
sol4 = to_process.groupby(['orgacom', 'client']).resample('B').asfreq()
```

*CPU times: user 4min 22s, sys: 8.01 s, total: 4min 30s
Wall time: 4min 30s*

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed that resampling on groupby can be slow. In my case, I used data reshaping for speed up,

```
df.set_index(['isin', 'report_date'])['val'].unstack(0).resample('M')
```

Comment: I need to do more operations after the resampling and reshaping the data will force me to rewrite all my following code. So unfortunately this method is not really an option at the moment

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing this. Use itertools.groupby() and list comprehension

```
import time
from itertools import groupby
print(time.time())
data = (
    ('SE001', '2018-12-31', 1),
    ('SE001', '2018-09-30', 2),
    ('SE001', '2018-06-31', 3),
    ('US001', '2018-10-31', 4),
    ('US001', '2018-07-31', 5),
)

aggr = [(key, sum([g[2] for g in grp])) for key, grp in groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda x: x[0])]
print(aggr)
print(time.time())


# 100,000 records
# 2.5 seconds
```

Comment: I might be mistaken but I do not see where this answer resamples the dates in second column?